# If S is a subset of inner product space V . which of the following option are True?

Tags: linear-algebra

If  S is  a subset of inner product space  V .

which  of the following option are  True ?

$a)$ $S \cap S ^{\perp}= \{0\}$

$b)$ $(S ^{\perp})^{\perp} = \ span(S)$

$c)$$(S ^{\perp})^{\perp} =S$

$d)$$ S^{\perp} \oplus \ span(S) = V $

## My attempt :

option $b$ and  $c$ are false  if  S will be  infinite dimensional subspaces

option 1)  will also false  if  we take  $S = \mathbb{R^ +}$

i thinks option 4 will be True ....

Any hints/solution will be appreciated

thanks  u